# getcontentresolver() is undefined for the type

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-fragments, import

Hi I am very new to java and am trying to create an app to upload pictures from my phones memory. I am trying to upload an image from my gallery to my app, I am getting the error "The method getConstentResolver() is undefined for the type Upload" How can I fix this?

Below is my code...

```
public class Upload extends Fragment {

    private static final int SELECTED_PICTURE=1;
    ImageView iv;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.upload, container, false);

        iv=(ImageView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

        return rootView;

    }

    public void btnClick(View v){
        Intent i=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
        startActivityForResult(i, SELECTED_PICTURE);

    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode,resultCode,data);
        switch(requestCode){
        case SELECTED_PICTURE:
            if(resultCode==RESULT_OK){
                Uri uri =data.getData();
                String[]projection={MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};

                Cursor cursor=getConstentResolver().query(uri,projection,null,null,null);
                cursor.moveToFirst();
                int columnIndex=cursor.getColumnIndex(projection[0]);
                String filePath=cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                cursor.close();

                Bitmap yourSelectedImage=BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath);
                Drawable d=new BitmapDrawable(yourSelectedImage);
                iv.setBackground(d);


            }
                    }
    }


    }
```

Comment: *getConstentResolver()* ?, try with `getActivity().getContentResolver().`

Comment: Hi see below my posted code it work fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this code:

```
public class EditProfileFragment extends Fragment {
private Button bt_browse;
private int REQUEST_CAMERA = 0, SELECT_FILE = 1;
private String uploadImagePath = "";

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.edit_profile_fragment,
            container, false);
    bt_browse = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.bt_browse);


    bt_browse.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            selectImage();
        }
    });



    return rootView;

}



private void selectImage() {
    final CharSequence[] items = { "Take Photo", "Choose from Library",
            "Cancel" };

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    builder.setTitle("Select Photo!");
    builder.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
            if (items[item].equals("Take Photo")) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                File f = new File(android.os.Environment
                        .getExternalStorageDirectory(), "temp.jpg");
                intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(f));
                startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CAMERA);
            } else if (items[item].equals("Choose from Library")) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(
                        Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                        android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                intent.setType("image/*");
                startActivityForResult(
                        Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select File"), SELECT_FILE);
            } else if (items[item].equals("Cancel")) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        }
    });
    builder.show();
}

public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CAMERA) {
            File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                    .toString());
            for (File temp : f.listFiles()) {
                if (temp.getName().equals("temp.jpg")) {
                    f = temp;
                    break;
                }
            }
            try {
                Bitmap bm;
                BitmapFactory.Options btmapOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();

                bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(f.getAbsolutePath(), btmapOptions);

                bm = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bm, 70, 70, true);
                iv_photo.setImageBitmap(bm);
                uploadImagePath = f.getAbsolutePath();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else if (requestCode == SELECT_FILE) {
            Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();

            String tempPath = getPath(selectedImageUri, getActivity());
            Bitmap bm;
            BitmapFactory.Options btmapOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(tempPath, btmapOptions);
            iv_photo.setImageBitmap(bm);
            uploadImagePath = tempPath;

        }
    }
}

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public String getPath(Uri uri, Activity activity) {
    String[] projection = { MediaColumns.DATA };
    Cursor cursor = activity.managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
    int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaColumns.DATA);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    return cursor.getString(column_index);

}



}
```

the image which you choose stored in uploadImagePath string.
just print it in Log then you understood..

For any further help dont hesitate to ask me..

Comment: Thanks for the reply, sorry for being a pain but i am getting the error iv_photo cannot be resolved, should i be adding iv_photo into my xml file or anything?

Comment: yes if you choose the photo then the photo will be display on that ImageView. Actually I am sorry to write that code.

Comment: Sorry I just dont under stand. how do i get rid of the error with iv_photo?

Comment: First declare a ImageView in xml file. 
After this Declare this line after private Button bt_browse; the line is private ImageView iv_photo;
After this Declare this line after bt_browse = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.bt_browse); the line is iv_photo = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.iv_photo);

Comment: One more thing my class is extends Fragment and i hope you are using Activity so  make sure to remove "rootView" and one more thing i am using onCreateView(-- ,--, --) and make sure that your function will be onCreate(--,--)

Comment: Sorry Acishek but is there anyway when you take a picture to then save it to your SD card with the above code?

Comment: When you take a picture the picture is saved in the sdCard. Please see the code:

File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                    .toString());
            for (File temp : f.listFiles()) {
                if (temp.getName().equals("temp.jpg")) {
                    f = temp;
                    break;
                }
            }

The above code will create a file named temp.jpg in your sdCard. So you can use it for further use.

Answer (score 0):

Hi see the below code it work fine.

```
package test.actionbariconupdate;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;


public class ActionBarIconUpdate extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_action_bar_icon_update2);
        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
        }
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

        private Button buttonclick;
        private ImageView imageview;

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
            Log.d("TAG","PlaceholderFragment");
        }


        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            setHasOptionsMenu(true);
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_action_bar_icon_update, container, false);
            imageview = (ImageView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.imageview);
            buttonclick = (Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.buttonclick);
            buttonclick.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    btnClick();
                }
            });
            return rootView;
        }

        @Override
        public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode,resultCode,data);
            switch(requestCode){
                case 1:
                    if(resultCode==RESULT_OK){
                        Uri uri =data.getData();
                        String[]projection={MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};

                        Cursor cursor= getActivity().getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null, null, null);
                        cursor.moveToFirst();
                        int columnIndex=cursor.getColumnIndex(projection[0]);
                        String filePath=cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                        cursor.close();

                        Bitmap yourSelectedImage= BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath);
                        Drawable d=new BitmapDrawable(yourSelectedImage);
                        imageview.setBackground(d);
                    }
            }
        }

        public void btnClick(){
            Intent i=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
            startActivityForResult(i, 1);

        }
    }
}
```